# Why does my script not work as a login shell?

Tags: zsh, login

I'm trying to make a shell for the desktop environment I'm designing which is just a configured Zsh, and I'm confused about how to pass along whether it's a login shell or not.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$0" in
-*) ZDOTDIR=/etc/tiles/zsh exec zsh -l "$@";;
*) ZDOTDIR=/etc/tiles/zsh exec zsh "$@";;
esac
```

I have installed it to `/bin/tiles-shell`, added that path to `/etc/shells`, and made it my shell with `chsh`.

The problem is it's never a login shell because `$0` seems to always be `/bin/tiles-shell`. I thought it would start with `-` when it should be a login shell?

Comment: If it's for zsh why have you indicated it's a sh script (top line)?

Comment: @roaima A wrapper can use whatever works before replacing itself with the actual tool.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski indeed it can, but I wanted to check it's what was intended

Comment: $0 would only *start* with `-` I think? So you'd want something more like `case $0 in -*)`

Comment: and shouldn't zsh recognize the `-` at the start of `$0` itself anyway? is the wrapper really needed for that?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver I think you're right there and I've updated it, but `$0` really is `/bin/tiles-shell`, I've printfed it to a file to check.

Comment: Seems like you're going out of your way to complicate something that should be very simple.  Why not just add `export ZDOTDIR=/etc/tiles/zsh` to either invidivual users' `~/.zshrc` files, or to the system-wide `/etc/zsh/zshrc` (optionally with a test for uid or username if you want this var set only for some users)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shebang mechanism wipes the old value of `argv[0]`: the kernel replaces it by the path to the interpreter.

The shell does not expose the value of `argv[0]` as `$0` when running a script from a file. `$0` is the name of the script file. I don't think zsh exposes its `argv[0]` through any other interface.

Demonstration script (for Linux):

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
echo "argv[0]=$(</proc/$$/cmdline tr \\0 \\n | head -n 1)"
echo "\$0=$0"
```

Output:

```
% ARGV0=foo zsh -c "$(cat a)"
argv[0]=foo
$0=foo
% ARGV0=foo zsh ./a
argv[0]=foo
$0=./a
% ARGV0=foo ./a
argv[0]=/bin/zsh
$0=./a
```

If you really want your login shell to be a script, make it a script that is dedicated to being a login shell.

Answer (score 1):

After Giles' answer I made it a binary and it works.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    putenv("ZDOTDIR=/etc/tiles/zsh");
    execv("/usr/bin/zsh", argv);
}
```